# Error in generating a hashed value for a table in DB2

Tags: python, db2, db2-luw

I used the below statement to generate the hashed value for the table.

```
select ACTNO,HASH_SHA1(concat(ACTNO,ACTKWD,ACTDESC)) from ACT order by ACTNO
```

where ACTNO(PRIMARY KEY) - SMALLINT, ACTKWD - CHAR, ACTDESC - VARCHAR

But when I tried to execute this statement am getting an error.

```
Error:ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "CONCAT" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884\r SQLCODE=-440
```

Can someone please help me to solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current versions of Db2-LUW offer a function named [HASH](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-hash).
To use the SHA1 algorithm, you specify argument 1 for the algorithm parameter. You should consider a stronger algorithm.

The CONCAT() function accepts only two arguments, but you give it three, so Db2 will throw an exception ( no such function). Use instead the concatenation operator `||`, after casting non character columns to varchar.

If your ACTKWD and ACTDESC columns allow NULL, use COALESCE().

Example for Db2-LUW:

`select actno, hash(varchar(actno)||coalesce(actkwd,'')||coalesce(actdesc,''),1) from act`